# A bash script for replacing patterns in multiple files names based on a 2-column mapping file

Tags: linux, bash, loops, rename

I have a bunch of files with mixed IDs in a directory (linux env.) and look like this:

```
SRR7821874_1.fastq.gz
SRR7821874_2.fastq.gz
SRR7821870_1.fastq.gz
SRR7821870_2.fastq.gz
```

I also have a 2-column tab-delimited file (called rename.tsv) based on which I try to replace IDs:

```
Read       Sample      
SRR7821874 GSM3385663 
SRR7821870 GSM3385659
```

Besides, I would like to concurrently change `_1` to `_S1_L001_R1_001` and `_2` to `_S1_L001_R2_001` in the file names, so the final result should look like this:

```
SRR7821874_1.fastq.gz --> GSM3385663_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
SRR7821874_2.fastq.gz --> GSM3385663_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
SRR7821870_1.fastq.gz --> GSM3385659_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
SRR7821870_2.fastq.gz --> GSM3385659_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I've tried the following script with no success as apparently it requires the full file names to rename them (just for ID replacement part):

```
while read -r Read Sample; do mv "$Read" "$Sample"; done < rename.tsv
```

Comment: How big is the table? Perhaps it will be most efficient if you first create an associative array which, i.e., maps SRR7821870 to GSM3385659. Then you loop through your files, calculate the new name, and perform the remaining.

Comment: The file `rename.tsv` that you show is not a 2-column tab-delimited file. It contains dashes, pipes, a header line, a separator line, etc. Please edit your question and show the exact format, or, if it is really what you show, update your explanation such that it matches the file format.

Comment: Thanks @RenaudPacalet! I edited that part. Please note that headers exist but without headers also should be fine.

Comment: @Erfanesi I updated my answer to show how to skip the header line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
tail -n+2 rename.tsv | while IFS=$'\t' read -r from to; do
  shopt -s nullglob
  for f in "${from}_"*.fastq.gz; do
    num="${f##*_}"; num="${num%%.*}"
    mv "$f" "${to}_S1_L001_R${num}_001.fastq.gz"
  done
done
```

We use `tail` to skip the header line, and we enable the `nullglob` bash option to expand `"${from}_"*.fastq.gz` as the null string instead of the pattern itself if no file matches. As this is part of a pipe the `nullglob` option is restored to its previous state at the end.

`"${f##*_}"` and `"${num%%.*}"` are two of the numerous [bash parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Note that you can use a more accurate pattern if needed. For instance, if you know that the number is always 1 or 2 you could replace `"${from}_"*.fastq.gz` with `"${from}_"[12].fastq.gz`. Or, if it is any one-digit number: `"${from}_"[0-9].fastq.gz`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk to create the mapping of old to new file names and then loop through that:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=$'\t' read -r old new; do
    echo mv -- "$old" "$new"
done < <(
    shopt -s nullglob
    sfx=".fastq.gz"
    awk -v sfx="$sfx" '
        NR == FNR {
            map[$1] = $2
            next
        }
        $1 in map {
            print $0, map[$1] "_S1_L001_R" $2+0 "_001" sfx
        }
    ' OFS='\t' FS='\t' rename.tsv FS='_' <(printf '%s\n' *"$sfx")
)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
mv -- SRR7821870_1.fastq.gz GSM3385659_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
mv -- SRR7821870_2.fastq.gz GSM3385659_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
mv -- SRR7821874_1.fastq.gz GSM3385663_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
mv -- SRR7821874_2.fastq.gz GSM3385663_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Thank you Ed! This awk alternative is very useful.